# How can I loop and access values of fields in OpenERP?

Tags: python, loops, odoo

I am learning to develop OpenERP modules, and one of the things I need to do is calculate the average of all the inputs from the user.

My idea was to loop the records while keeping the sum and the count and then make the average, but I can't seem to understand how to access the value for the `total` field for each record in the `sim.students` table

Here is part of my code

```
def get_text(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
    result = {}
    i = 0
    for id in ids:
        print self.browse(cr,uid,id,['total'])
        print id
        i = i+1
        print i

    return result
```

But the result of printing `self.browse(cr,uid,id,['total'])` returns me `browse_record(sim.student, 3)`and not the total itself.

I know this must be really simple but I can't seem to figure out how to get to that value.

Any tip much appreciated

Comment: what kind of object is self?

Comment: is part of the class `class student(osv.osv):` does that help?

Comment: yeah. what does self.browse(cr,uid,id).total do, if anything?

Comment: @Raufio you are a genius! I knew it was something easy but for some reason I thought I had to put it between []. Please make it an answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is what I got from [here](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html#osv.osv.osv.browse):

```
browse(cr ,uid, select, context=None, list_process=None, fields_process=None)
```

where:

```
cr = database cursor
uid = user id
select = id or list of ids
context = context arguments like lang, time zone
```

It returns an object with all the fields accessible by dot notation. So you can do something like:

```
records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
for rec in records:
     print rec.total
     print rec.otherfield
```

or if you like list comprehensions:

```
records = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
totals = [rec.total for rec in records]
average = sum(totals)/len(totals)
```